# Trying to connect to database using Postgres but it isn't able to translate the address on Amazon server to Amazon database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, psycopg2

Getting this error when trying to connect to a database on Amazon. This is from an Amazon server.

> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "domain-stg-postgres.caxdkvuertc9.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/projectname_dev" to address: Name or service not known

I'm setting this here:

```
db["host"] = parser['ebean.datasource.databaseUrl'].replace("${ebean.datasource.name}", db_name)
```

Why would my host name not be working? Am I missing something obvious here?

This seems to be an Amazon specific problem?

Comment: This is your hostname: `domain-stg-postgres.caxdkvuertc9.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com` this is your database name `projectname_dev`. You shouldn't have `/projectname_dev` as part of the hostname.

Comment: Ah, I thought the database and URL arguments were necessary for correct pathing to Amazon databases. Changing this does seem to work. Feel free to answer if you want me to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your hostname: `domain-stg-postgres.caxdkvuertc9.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com` this is your database name `projectname_dev`. You shouldn't have `/projectname_dev` as part of the hostname.